# jQuery - How to get current div id when class displays more than once

Tags: jquery

New to jQuery. I have a 'resultsDiv' div that renders multiple table divs using data retrieved from a array.

[image]

When I click 'addSubTask' icon I append a new cell to the current row. I'm finally able to see the id of the table using the following. The following displays "Finance".

```
$("div.table").closest("div").prop("id");
```

How can I see 'Places To Go' or 'Travel' when I append to the current list.

Thank you for reviewing!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest("div").prop("id");
```

should work